# Semantic-UI: Cannot access icons ("CORS request not http")

Tags: javascript, php, html, cors, semantic-ui

I'm trying to make the following example work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Understanding - Main</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#menu-opener').click(function(){ $('.sidebar.menu').sidebar('toggle') })
    </script>

      <div class="ui container">
        <div class="ui sidebar vertical menu">
          <div class="item">Home</div>
          <div class="item">Map</div>
          <div class="item">1. Prehist</div>
          <div class="item">2. Ancient</div>
        </div>
        <i id="menu-opener" class="content icon"></i>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the icon doesn't load and the console prints

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:////home/abcd/Web/ExplainSemantic/semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

I tried googling this error but every instance that I found involved a person querying an online database.  Given that I don't know PHP it would be nice not to have to learn it to fix this bug--although, if that's what's required, I guess that's the rabbithole I'm down now.  But if there's a non-PHP resolution I'd appreciate learning it.  Thanks!

Comment: It is trying to get the icon via http and is saying that isn't allowed, it needs to be via https.

Comment: @ChrisCousins Is there a way to make that happen ...?  Or a way to make get it not from https but get around whatever this thing is?

Comment: Or maybe put another way: What's the point of downloading these files if you can't access them locally?  There has to be a way right?

Comment: How are you running this? Is it locally on your own webserver? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: @ChrisCousins Entirely on my local computer, just a desktop.  I figure I'll design the page for now and when I'm ready, shop for a host.

Answer (score 1):

Font files such as `.woff2`  must be placed on the server!

Can't use `file://` protocol to access it

Comment: So there's just no way to use these files locally while I'm testing and designing the page?

Comment: I think you can extract the font file, put it on the server, and modify the location of the font file referenced in semantic.min.css, pointing to the request address on your server.

Comment: `https://expressionengine.com/learn/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors`. Maybe this can help you!